# Angular ui-router: How to get URL parameters working with ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-click, url-parameters

I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass a URL parameter through an `ng-click` to `$state.go`.

**Controller**

```
angular.module('app').controller('screeningsController', ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', function($scope, $state, $stateParams){

    //Change state when image is clicked
    $scope.swipeUrl = function(){
        $state.go("screenings.images", {image: image});
    }

    //When image is closed, revert back
    $scope.swipeRemove = function(){
        $state.go("screenings");
    }
}]);
```

In my controller, I'm not sure how to format the URL parameter in the `$state.go` of the function `swiperURL`. Right now, I have it set to `{image: image}`.

**States**

```
$stateProvider
        .state('screenings', {
            url: '/screenings/',
            templateUrl: 'pages/screenings.php',
            controller: 'screeningsController'
         })

         .state('screenings.images', {
            url: ":image",
            controller: 'screeningsController'
        })
```

**View**

```
<div class='img_div' ng-click="swipeUrl(test)">
```

The `ng-click` in the view triggers the function `swiperURL` in the controller. I was trying to pass the string "test" as the URL parameter by declaring `ng-click="swiperURL(test)`.

Comment: your function doesn't accept a parameter, so adding a parameter on the function call has no effect.  accept a parameter in your `swipeUrl` function, and then you can pass it on in the call to `$state.go`.

Comment: @Claies Do I need to use $stateParams to do that?

Comment: you already have a `params` object (`{image: image}`).  just pass whatever your function receives instead.

Comment: So make it `ng-click="swipeUrl()` - don't pass anything?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you, sorry.

Comment: no, you are backwards.  you are passing a value to the function, so accept  the value in the function, then pass the value as the params object.  the same way any other function call would work.

Comment: `$scope.swipeUrl = function(somestring){
        $state.go("screenings.images", {image: somestring});
    }` as an example.

Comment: What is the significance of `somestring` here? Is `somestring` the same as `ng-click=swipeUrl(somestring)`?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how a string from the view makes its way to the controller.

Comment: firstly, `<div class='img_div' ng-click="swipeUrl(test)">` isn't passing a string, it is passing a **variable** called `test`. If you want to pass a string, it needs quotes (`"test"`). secondly, this is really basic javascript here;  you passed something to the function, so the function has to have a variable to receive the thing you passed to it, then that thing is passed on to the next function.  It doesn't really matter what the name of the variable is in the function, it doesn't have to match the variable in the `ng-click`....

Comment: Thanks. So `ng-click="swipeUrl("test")"` passes a string to the function, and then `$scope.swipeUrl = function(somestring)` would have "test" stored in `somestring`? `somestring` is just the placeholder of test at that point?

Comment: yes, that's correct.  then in the `$state.go`, you are passing an object, the object will look like `{image : somestring}`, which means that `image === 'test'`.  then in the new route, `url: image` will end up making `url === 'test'`.

Comment: That did it. Thank you. That was extremely helpful. Would accept this as an answer if I could.